# What is $Latest in lambda function version and how to get it in proper way?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

I want to  get the lambda version name
I use the context object that is passed to the lamdba_handler method.
I use function_version

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
     print(context.function_version)
```

The output is `$Latest` only. I actually want version name not `$Latest`.
what should I do??

Comment: Are you running the function from the Test button on AWS Lambda Console?

Comment: yes i am running by clicking test button

Comment: Then you need to click on `Qualifiers` then click on the version you wanna test with, then click on the `Test` button.

Comment: Thanks that works fine but if I want to get deployment stage info, name etc in my lamda function what method I should call?

Comment: I don't know. For follow up questions, instead of commenting you should create a new question for that.